# Is there a program for removing purple fringing for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, chromatic-aberration, color-fringing, bibble

Some of my photos taken in bright daylight with film era lenses show purple fringing.

To remove it I have tried:

1. Bibble 5, does not seem to have any way of doing this.
2. I used the hue-saturation control in GIMP, but I find it tedious and ineffective.
3. I found some instructions on how Darktable can be patched to include a purple defringing module from a git repository, this might work but the whole idea of patching up a test version of Darktable from git seems not all that tempting to me.

Is there any simple to install and use program that will run on Ubuntu and preferably in Bibble 5 for removing purple fringing?

Comment: The defringe module is now part of darktable releases, but it's not really the right module for correcting lateral chromatic aberration anyway. There's a dedicated chromatic aberration module for that. The defringe module is helpful for desaturating the purple fringes that occur in overexposed high-contrast areas, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RawTherapee can do this (and can handle not only raw files, despite the name). I don't know if it can integrate into Bibble but I doubt it. See [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DHLb_6xNQsEInxiuU8pz1-sWNinnj09bpBUA4_Vl8w8) for the manual.

There are three possible ways, one in the "raw" tab, one in "change/manipulate/transform" tab (fourth tab, I don't know the English name), and one in the "detail" tab (second tab). The last one allows the finest control.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you are looking for in any of the applications you might use is called *Chromatic Aberration Correction* and is usually one of several options in a *Lens Correction* section/tab of the program. Do any of the applications you are using include a *Lens Correction* module?

You might also find the answers to [other questions tagged with *chromatic aberration*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chromatic-aberration) helpful.

Comment: There is indeed a _Chromatic Aberration Correction_ under _Lens Correction_ in Bibble 5 but apparently it only supports red/cyan and blue/yellow correction no purple correction. I found the _Color Picker tool_ under _Color Correction_ in Bibble 5, it allows me to pick the purple color and correct it, similar to what I did in Gimp. However RawTherapee seems like the best tool for this purpose.

Comment: Purple is a combination of red and blue...

Comment: Red=-0.3 and Blue=-0.5 in the _Chromatic Aberration Correction_ tool seems indeed to work for removing purple fringing.